# How to declare and initialize an associative array with string as keys and arrays as value

Tags: d

I am new to D.
I am looking for the equivalent of this C++ declaration

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> the_value;
std::map<std::string,the_value> the_table;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this probably:

```
string[][string] the_table;
```

example:

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string[][string] the_table = ["k1" : ["v1", "v2"], "k2" : ["v3", "v4"]];
    writeln(the_table);
}
```

Comment: And if you prefer to make it clearer, you can use `alias Values = string[];` and `Values[string] table = ...;`.